# Asp code to Download data from web server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ftp

Can i make asp application or mvc application that can download data from other server (site) using ftp. I have 2 web sites and i want to download a file from one site to another using ftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Example copied from [How to Download Files with FTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The example is for a console app, but I think you can figure quite easily how to adapt it to your site's structure.

One thing you might consider is just hosting the file on the site (like normal HTTP) and then download it via [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instead of FTP.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();  
        }
    }
}
```